# Summing two datetime columns

Tags: pandas, datetime, sum

I have a datadframe with two columns, for example

```
A                B 
00:01:05         2018-10-10 23:58:10
```

and I want to get a third column C which is the sum of A + B

```
A                B                             C
00:01:05         2018-10-10 23:58:10           2018-10-10 23:59:15
```

If I do:

```
df['C']= df['A'] + df['B']
```

I get

```
cannot add DatetimeArray and DatetimeArray
```

Comment: Convert them to `pd.Timedelta first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is your sample dataframe,

```
sample = pd.DataFrame()

sample['A'] = ['00:01:05']
sample['B'] = ['2018-10-10 23:58:10']
```

convert column `B` to pd.Timstamp and `A` to pd.Timedelta like this,

```
sample['B'] = pd.to_datetime(sample['B'])
sample['A'] = pd.to_timedelta(sample['A'], unit='m')
```

And then add the columns normally,

```
sample['C'] = sample['B'] + sample['A']

    A                    B                     C
0   00:01:05    2018-10-10 23:58:10     2018-10-10 23:59:15
```

Answer (score 6):

Convert column `A` to timedeltas by [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) and if necessary column `B` to [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['00:01:05'],
                   'B':['2018-10-10 23:58:10']})

df['C'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['A']) + pd.to_datetime(df['B'])
print (df)
          A                    B                   C
0  00:01:05  2018-10-10 23:58:10 2018-10-10 23:59:15
```

If column `A` contains python times:

```
df['C'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['A'].astype(str)) + pd.to_datetime(df['B'])
```